# MouseDoubleClick on ListItem with MVVM in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, command

I want to show dialog when i double click any of the list items. But the flow of the program never go in the ShowTextCommand property. I get the list of the names (that works fine) but I can't get the dialog. This is my XAML:

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding List}"  >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"  Command="{Binding ShowTextCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></MouseBinding>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

this is my Command class:

```
public class EnterTextCommand : ICommand
{
    public EnterTextCommand(TekstoviViewModel vm)
    {
        ViewModel = vm;
    }
    private TekstoviViewModel ViewModel;
    #region ICommand interface
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
       // return ViewModel.CanExecute;
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ViewModel.EnterText();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and the view model

```
 private ICommand command;
    public ICommand ShowTextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (command == null)
                command = new EnterTextCommand(this);
            return command;
        }
 internal void EnterText()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Event Success");
    }
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` can't find the `command`, specify the full path to it using `ElementName` Binding

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding List}"  x:Name="MainList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"  Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowTextCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ElementName=MainList}"></MouseBinding>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```